# Report Builder 3.0 - How can I do a Nested Lookup

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, reporting, lookup, reportbuilder3.0

I’m hoping someone might be able to assist me with a small issue I’m having with a report. I'm new to Report Builder and everything I do I pretty much learn along the way.

I’m unable to perform a nested lookup in Report Builder and I’ve tried looking for an alternative but haven’t had much luck.

This is what I wanted to do but was unable to due to the restriction on nesting:

```
Lookup(lookup(Fields!sr_service_recid.Value, Fields!TicketNbr.Value, Fields!Parent.Value, "Service_Parent"), Fields!SR_Service_RecID.Value, Fields!PO_Number.Value, "Ticket_PO")
```

Basically I need to reference the `sr_service_recid` of the Current Ticket against the Parent Ticket in order to reference the `PO_Number` of the Parent Ticket.

I’ve been though majority of the tables and views available to me (there are a bucket load so I can’t say I’ve been through them all) and haven’t found a different way to link these values.

Do you perhaps have any ideas I could try that might allow me to do something similar to the above nested lookup expression? A nudge in a fresh direction would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Dane

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty new to all of this so excuse the simplicity of my required solution.

I added a new Dataset to my report with the below query, allowing me to link the respective data I required.

```
SELECT
  v_rpt_Service.Parent
  ,v_rpt_Service.TicketNbr
  ,sr_service.po_number
FROM
v_rpt_Service
left join sr_service on (sr_service.sr_service_recid = v_rpt_service.parent)
```